# Comparing the keys in multiple JSON files used for translations in an Angular application

Tags: c#, json.net

I maintain a number of projects, and several of them feature Angular front-ends. These projects need to be available in multiple languages, at the very least French and Dutch and preferably also in English. In order to do that, Angular supports [Internationalization](https://angular.io/guide/i18n-overview) and in our apps this means multiple JSON files named "en.json", "fr.json", "nl.json".

However, these often grow large over time, and sometimes developers forget to add a required key (plus its translated value) to every file.

I looked for a tool that could compare two Angular files, only considering the keys of those files (since the values are translations and thus different more often than not); however, I did not find such a tool. I also didn't find and code that would offer this functionality, and thus I decided to write my own.

Below is the result, a console app in .NET Framework 4.8:

```
internal class Program
{
    private static void Main()
    {
        new Runner().Execute();
    }
}
```

I try to keep `Program.cs` light and usually create a `Runner` class to handle the logic (this also allows me to avoid the bother with `static` methods etc.):

```
internal class Runner
{
    private static string rootFolder = @"C:\dev\website\src\assets\i18n";

    private Dictionary<string, List<string>> _keysByFileName;

    public void Execute()
    {
        Trace.TraceInformation("--------------------------------------------------------------");

        var fileNames = new[] { "en.json", "fr.json", "nl.json" };

        _keysByFileName = fileNames.ToDictionary(fileName => fileName, GetKeys);

        Compare(fileNames[0], fileNames[1]);
        Compare(fileNames[0], fileNames[2]);
        Compare(fileNames[1], fileNames[0]);
        Compare(fileNames[1], fileNames[2]);
        Compare(fileNames[2], fileNames[0]);
        Compare(fileNames[2], fileNames[1]);
    }

    private void Compare(string fileName1, string fileName2)
    {
        var itemsOnlyIn1 = _keysByFileName[fileName1].Except(_keysByFileName[fileName2]).ToList();

        if (itemsOnlyIn1.Any())
        {
            Trace.TraceWarning($"The following keys are present in {fileName1}"
                               + $" but missing from {fileName2}:"
                               + $" [{string.Join("], [", itemsOnlyIn1)}].");
        }
    }

    private List<string> GetKeys(string fileName)
    {
        var contents = File.ReadAllText(Path.Combine(rootFolder, fileName));
        
        var jObject = JObject.Parse(contents);

        var keys = GetKeys(jObject);
        
        return keys.Distinct().OrderBy(x => x).ToList();
    }

    private List<string> GetKeys(JObject jObject, List<string> parents = null)
    {
        if (parents == null)
        {
            parents = new List<string>();
        }

        var keys = new List<string>();

        foreach (var jProperty in jObject.Children<JProperty>())
        {
            keys.AddRange(GetKeys(jProperty, new List<string>(parents)));
        }

        return keys;
    }

    private List<string> GetKeys(JProperty jProperty, List<string> parents = null)
    {
        if (parents == null)
        {
            parents = new List<string>();
        }

        var keys = new List<string>();

        var name = jProperty.Name;
        parents.Add(name);

        var fullName = string.Join(".", parents);
        keys.Add(fullName);

        var children = jProperty.Children<JObject>().ToList();

        if (children.Any())
        {
            foreach (var child in children)
            {
                keys.AddRange(GetKeys(child, new List<string>(parents)));
            }
        }

        return keys;
    }
}
```

Note that I use NLog to convert the calls to `Trace` into log file entries by adding this to the `App.config` (combined with a custom `NLog.config`):

```
  <system.diagnostics>
    <trace autoflush="true">
      <listeners>
        <add name="MyNLogTraceListener" type="NLog.NLogTraceListener, NLog" />
      </listeners>
    </trace>
  </system.diagnostics>
```

The log entries look like this:

> The following keys are present in en.json but missing from fr.json: [customerdirection], [metricrequestview.dialog.abort], [metricrequestview.dialog.close], [tooltips.btn.requestmetricsdeletion].
>
> The following keys are present in en.json but missing from nl.json: [cirelation.create.application], [cirelation.create.environment], [tooltips.btn.requestmetricsdeletion].
>
> The following keys are present in fr.json but missing from en.json: [applicationexternalcontactview.editexternalcontact], [customerServiceManagerApplicationLevel], [delete.failed.metricrequest], [delete.successful.environment].
>
> The following keys are present in fr.json but missing from nl.json: [cirelation.create.application], [cirelation.create.environment], [delete.successful.environment].
>
> The following keys are present in nl.json but missing from en.json: [applicationexternalcontactview.editexternalcontact], [customerServiceManagerApplicationLevel], [delete.failed.metricrequest].
>
> The following keys are present in nl.json but missing from fr.json: [customerdirection], [metricrequestview.dialog.abort], [metricrequestview.dialog.close].

I'm least happy with the method `private List<string> GetKeys(JProperty jProperty, List<string> parents = null)`: it feels clunky and unstructured.

Answer (score 2):

Focussing on your `GetKeys` methods, I think you can simplify them by passing a `path` instead of a list of parents. There's also no point in checking `Any` before doing a `foreach`. Something like this should work (untested):

```
private List<string> GetKeys(JObject jObject, string path = null)
{
    var keys = new List<string>();

    foreach (var jProperty in jObject.Children<JProperty>())
    {
        keys.AddRange(GetKeys(jProperty, path));
    }

    return keys;
}

private List<string> GetKeys(JProperty jProperty, string path = null)
{
    var keys = new List<string>();
    var fullName = path == null ? jProperty.Name : $"{path}.{jProperty.Name}";
    keys.Add(fullName);

    var children = jProperty.Children<JObject>().ToList();

    foreach (var child in children)
    {
        keys.AddRange(GetKeys(child, fullName));
    }

    return keys;
}
```

---

I think you're doing this in a harder way than you need to. Look at your `Execute` method, how does it change with another file?

```
public void Execute()
{
    Trace.TraceInformation("--------------------------------------------------------------");

    var fileNames = new[] { "en.json", "fr.json", "nl.json", "new.json" };

    _keysByFileName = fileNames.ToDictionary(fileName => fileName, GetKeys);

    Compare(fileNames[0], fileNames[1]);
    Compare(fileNames[0], fileNames[2]);
    Compare(fileNames[0], fileNames[3]); // new
    Compare(fileNames[1], fileNames[0]);
    Compare(fileNames[1], fileNames[2]);
    Compare(fileNames[1], fileNames[3]); // new
    Compare(fileNames[2], fileNames[0]);
    Compare(fileNames[2], fileNames[1]);
    Compare(fileNames[2], fileNames[3]); // new
    Compare(fileNames[3], fileNames[0]); // new
    Compare(fileNames[3], fileNames[1]); // new
    Compare(fileNames[3], fileNames[2]); // new
}
```

Ouch, this isn't a scalable solution. Each new file adds many new comparisons.

I would try to do something like this, typed into CR so apologies for syntax/logic errors but I hope it illustrates the point:

```
private class KeyInformation
{
    public KeyInformation(string key)
    {
        Key = key;
    }

    public string Key { get; }
    public ISet<string> Files { get; } = new HashSet<T>();
}

public void Execute()
{
    var fileNames = new[] { "en.json", "fr.json", "nl.json" };
    var keyInformation = new Dictionary<string, KeyInformation>();
    foreach (var fileName in fileNames)
    {
        foreach (var key in GetKeys(fileName))
        {
            if (!keyInformation.TryGetValue(key, out var info))
            {
                info = new KeyInformation(key);
                keyInformation[key] = info;
            }
            // N.b. Add returns false if key already exists. You can use this to check for duplicate keys in the same file.
            info.Files.Add(fileName);
        }
    }

    var entriesToDoSomethingWith = keyInformation
        .Select(kvp => kvp.Value)
        .Where(i => i.Files.Count != fileNames.Count);

    foreach (var entry in entriesToDoSomethingWith)
    {
       // Print info for entry.Key
       // Present in entry.Files
       // Missing in fileNames.ExceptWith(entry.Files)
    }
}
```

Adding a new file now only changes the fileNames array :)

Comment: Yes, that bit is indeed not scalable, but this was a quick and dirty solution and I didn't want to bother with figuring out that logic. (For me it was always going to be those three files.) WRT using a path, yeah, that might be simpler.

Comment: That's fair enough. I am terrible at covering all the cases in combinations like that so I tend to avoid ever having to do it. The type of solution I proposed has become quite formulaic for me over the years - it seems to pop up a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Focusing only to this `List<string> GetKeys(JProperty jProperty, List<string> parents)` method here is my rewritten version:

```
parents ??= new List<string>();
parents.Add(jProperty.Name);

var keys = new List<string>()
{
    string.Join(".", parents)
};

foreach (var child in jProperty.Children<JObject>())
{
    keys.AddRange(GetKeys(child, new List<string>(parents)));
}

return keys;
```

---

Let's see them one-by-one

```
if (parents == null)
{
    parents = new List<string>();
}
```

- Here you can take advantage of the [??= null-coalescing assignment operator](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-coalescing-operator)

```
var name = jProperty.Name;
parents.Add(name);
```

- Since `name` is used only once inside the `Add` call that's why I inlined it
- I've also moved the `parents.Add` call right next to the optional `parents` initialization

```
var keys = new List<string>();

var fullName = string.Join(".", parents);
keys.Add(fullName);
```

- Since `fullName` is used only once inside the `Add` call that's why I inlined it
- Rather than calling explicitly the `Add` method I took advantage of collection initialization

```
var children = jProperty.Children<JObject>().ToList();

if (children.Any())
{
    foreach (var child in children)
    {
        keys.AddRange(GetKeys(child, new List<string>(parents)));
    }
}
```

- I think you do not need to call `ToList` on the `Children` call since it returns a `JEnumerable` which can be used in the `foreach`
- The `Any` check is not needed because if the collection is empty then the foreach will simply skip the loop body
- Since the `Children` [could not return](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/e44ab3348fabcbe9ed6b5053b706a9e10b945ba1/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Linq/JContainer.cs#L266) `null` that's why you don't need to do a null check, otherwise it would be advisable